# Netless appId for agora project in web platform

Tags: agora.io

How can I generate a new NETLESS_APP_ID to run agora classroom in web platform ?
I searched it on google. but nothing found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable Whiteboard and click on config
AppIdentifier is your NETLESS_APP_ID